# Integral of the square of a function

Tags: calculus

I have an integral of the square of a function ($f(x)\cdot f(x)$ from $0$ to infinity) that's very hard to compute. I just need to know the sign of its value. Is it always non-negative? If not, what are the conditions for non-negativity?

Answer (score 3):

The integrand will be non-negative, so the same goes for the integral (it may be infinite).

Comment: That was quick and helpful. Thanks Stranger.

Answer (score 1):

suppose $$f(x)=\frac{i}{x+1},$$
$$f(x)\cdot f(x)=-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$
$$\int_0^\infty \left(f(x)\right)^2 \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty -\frac{1}{(x+1)^2} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=-\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=-\left[ -\frac{1}{(x+1)} \right]_0^\infty$$
$$=\left[ \frac{1}{(x+1)} \right]_0^\infty$$
$$=(0)-(1)$$
$$\therefore \quad \int_0^\infty \left(f(x)\right)^2 \,\mathrm{d}x=-1$$
from this, we can see that if $f(x)$ takes complex values, its integral is not always positive (though nor is it always negative)

Comment: The integral can easily be non-negative even if the integrand is sometimes not real. Consider a function $f$ that takes a small imaginary value for a small region and otherwise takes large real values. Overall the real parts will dominate the integral giving a non-negative result.

Comment: good point (I didn't mean to state all the conditions, only to show that there is a contradiction)